# Can you access the mainBundle from the non-UI thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have some code which statically accesses `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, but the documentation doesn't make clear whether this can be accessed from a non-UI thread. I know all UI operations must be executed on the UI thread, but is the `mainBundle` classed as a UI element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class prefix begins with NS* not UI* so no, the mainBundle isn't part of the UI subsystem and you can access it from a background thread.

It's worth remembering that the contents of the `mainBundle` on iOS are immutable... so you are only really going to get useful info by reading from `mainBundle` not writing.

Answer (score -2):

`NSBundle` is considered [thread-unsafe](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html). While it could be accessed from background threads it can be accessed from only one thread at a time.

Comment: I believe the Apple docs actually say that `NSBundle` is thread-safe.

Comment: The link provided in this answer links to a page that lists NSBundle as thread-safe.